# Forcing Firefox to present the wrong client certificate

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

I'm developing a web application which expects clients to authenticate with client certificates. In order to test its behavior, I want to be able to throw wrong certificates at it. Of course I could also do this with command-line tools, but that's inconvenient. Is there any way to inhibit Firefox's default client-side pre-filtering?

Everything works fine in the optimistic scenario (i.e. when I import a certificate signed by the same CA as the server's) – but Firefox doesn't offer me the option to select a self-signed certificate, for instance, per [this older question](https://superuser.com/questions/1043415/firefox-doesnt-ask-me-for-a-certificate-when-visiting-a-site-that-needs-one/1118202).

Answer (score 0):

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/30771123/6368697 I like the idea of having different profiles and importing in each of them only the certificate you want to use. The question also speaks about a `security.default_personal_cert` parameter.

Otherwise you need to clear history to make sure Firefox will ask again for a certificate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24041645/6368697

However since Firefox is so much against self-signed certificate, it may be reluctant to use one, whatever you do.

Comment: I'm happy with using a certificate signed by the wrong CA, that wouldn't be the problem. I just don't want Firefox to force me into using a valid one...

Comment: I looked into security.default_personal_cert, and it turns out you can set it via the UI to either "Ask every time" or "Select automatically" (not the actual strings). I can't use that to force a specific certificate, or to override its pre-filtering mechanism.